# What is the DRY way to get Theorem 1(a)?

Tags: cross-referencing, memoir, cleveref

I am typesetting a document with the `memoir` class and the `cleveref` package.  Often I have a numbered theorem and enumerated parts.  I would like to be able to refer to a part of a theorem as simply as possible.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm}
My big theorem
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item\label{thm!simple} Simple case
\item\label{thm!complex} Complex case
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\Cref{thm}\cref{thm!simple} % Theorem1item a

\Cref{thm}\ref{thm!simple}  % Theorem 1a
\Cref{thm}(\ref{thm!simple})% Theorem 1(a), but redundant coding

\end{document}
```

None of these is optimal.  If I change the label format, I have to change every reference, which goes against the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) mantra.

My best workaround so far is to redefine the reference format, as in:

```
\begin{theorem}\label{thm2}
My second big theorem
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\crefformat{enumi}{#2(#1)#3}
\item\label{thm2!simple} Simple case
\item\label{thm2!complex} Complex case
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\Cref{thm2}\cref{thm2!simple} % Theorem2(a)
```

Then if I want to change the label format I still have to change it in two places, but at least they are next to each other.

I guess the next level hack would be to look into how `memoir` extends `enumerate` and have it update `\crefformat` at the same time.  But before I got my hands dirty I thought I would ask the hive.

Comment: You could use `enumitem`. With `\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]` both `\ref{thm!simple}` and (after saying `\crefformat{enumi}{#2#1#3}` in the preamble) `\cref{thm!simple}` will give `(a)`.

Comment: I normally use enumitem, but since memoir duplicates the enumerate package I thought I was not able to use it here.  Might work.

Comment: As fas as I know `enumitem` does work with `memoir`. I'm not a `memoir` user, though...

Comment: Do you always want the theorem number in front of the item letter?

Comment: @egreg: No, not always.

Answer (score 5):

Define your own command for splitting the label.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\newenvironment{tenumerate}[1][]
  {\enumerate[label=\textup(\alph*\textup),ref=(\alph*),#1]}
  {\endenumerate}

\newcommand{\dref}[1]{\dodref\cref#1\relax}
\newcommand{\Dref}[1]{\dodref\Cref#1\relax}
\def\dodref#1#2!#3\relax{#1{#2}\ref{#2!#3}}

\begin{document}
First of all a lemma.
\begin{lemma}\label{lem}
Here it is:
\begin{tenumerate}
\item\label{lem!a} A
\item\label{lem!b} B
\end{tenumerate}
\end{lemma}

And a wonderful theorem follows.

\begin{theorem}\label{thm}
My big theorem:
\begin{tenumerate}
\item\label{thm!simple} Simple case
\item\label{thm!complex} Complex case
\end{tenumerate}
\end{theorem}

\Dref{thm!simple} and \dref{thm!complex}; we
can also use \ref{thm!simple} or \cref{thm!complex}.

The proof follows immediately from \Dref{lem!b}.

\end{document}
```

[image]